# Top 10 HashTags in Cypher Query

Tags: graph

I'm trying to fetch the top 10 unique hashtags used between certain dates from the Twitter dataset. However, if I define `WITH` again after where it will delete the previous variables, and if I limit the results before where it does not show correct results.

Comment: If the dataset is public, please provide some sort of download link, so that we can verify it as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should try this:

```
MATCH (h:Hashtag)<-[:TAGS]-(t:Tweet) 
WITH h.tag AS hashtag, date(t.postedTimeStamp) AS PostDate
WHERE date({year:2021, month:8, day:25}) <= PostDate <=date({year:2021, month:8, day:28})
WITH PostDate, hashtag, count(hashtag) AS tagCount
ORDER BY tagCount DESC
RETURN PostDate, COLLECT(hashtag)[0..10] AS tags
```

Comment: I tried this but the last LIMIT tag will limit down all the results rather than limiting the tags actually.

Comment: Updated the answer, it will give 10 tags per date.

Comment: Top10 means the tags should have most number of occurence in relation to tweets. Without sorting the count, you will get 10 randomized hastags.

Comment: Thanks @jose_bacoy. I missed it. Updated the answer,

Comment: when you include hashtag with count(hashtag), it will always return count(hashtag)=1. You cannot add hashtag on the WITH clause when you are counting it. Please check it again. thanks.

Comment: That depends on how data is stored. For example, if `PostDate` is `date({year:2021, month:8, day:25})`, and `hashTag` is `ABC`. Then the count will return all the counts of `ABC` on that date, not only one. In the end, hashTag is a string, not a node. What do you think @jose_bacoy.